# namespaces for enum types - best practices

Tags: c++, enums, scope, nested

Often, one needs several enumerated types together.  Sometimes, one has a name clash.  Two solutions to this come to mind: use a namespace, or use 'larger' enum element names.  Still, the namespace solution has two possible implementations: a dummy class with nested enum, or a full blown namespace.

I'm looking for pros and cons of all three approaches.

Example:

```
// oft seen hand-crafted name clash solution
enum eColors { cRed, cColorBlue, cGreen, cYellow, cColorsEnd };
enum eFeelings { cAngry, cFeelingBlue, cHappy, cFeelingsEnd };
void setPenColor( const eColors c ) {
    switch (c) {
        default: assert(false);
        break; case cRed: //...
        break; case cColorBlue: //...
        //...
    }
 }


// (ab)using a class as a namespace
class Colors { enum e { cRed, cBlue, cGreen, cYellow, cEnd }; };
class Feelings { enum e { cAngry, cBlue, cHappy, cEnd }; };
void setPenColor( const Colors::e c ) {
    switch (c) {
        default: assert(false);
        break; case Colors::cRed: //...
        break; case Colors::cBlue: //...
        //...
    }
 }


 // a real namespace?
 namespace Colors { enum e { cRed, cBlue, cGreen, cYellow, cEnd }; };
 namespace Feelings { enum e { cAngry, cBlue, cHappy, cEnd }; };
 void setPenColor( const Colors::e c ) {
    switch (c) {
        default: assert(false);
        break; case Colors::cRed: //...
        break; case Colors::cBlue: //...
        //...
    }
  }
```

Comment: First of all, I would use Color::Red, Feeling:Angry, etc

Comment: the "c" prefix on everything hurts readability.

Comment: Note that you don't need to name the enum as in `enum e {...}`, enums can be anonymous, ie `enum {...}`, which makes much more sense when wrapped in namespace or class.

Comment: if you have an un-named enum, what is its type?
eg: enum FOO{}; void bar(FOO e); but if we have enum{} void bar2(???);

Comment: @kralyk: You're right, but only for classes. For namespaces, it's better to retain the enums non-anonymous, because you cannot use the namespace's name itself as a type name; you can use only the name of that inner enum for that.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

**Original C++03 answer:**

The *benefit* from a `namespace` (over a `class`) is that you can use `using` declarations when you want.

The *problem* with using a `namespace` is that namespaces can be expanded elsewhere in the code.  In a large project, you would not be guaranteed that two distinct enums don't both think they are called `eFeelings`

For simpler-looking code, I use a `struct`, as you presumably want the contents to be public.

If you're doing any of these practices, you are ahead of the curve and probably don't need to scrutinize this further.

**Newer, C++11 advice:**

If you are using C++11 or later, `enum class` will implicitly scope the enum values within the enum's name.

With `enum class` you will lose implicit conversions and comparisons to integer types, but in practice that may help you discover ambiguous or buggy code.

Comment: I agree with the struct-idea.  And thanks for the compliment:)

Comment: +1 I couldn't remember the C++11 "enum class" syntax. Without that feature, enums are incomplete.

Comment: Is their an option to use "using" for the implicit scope of the "enum class".
e.g. Will adding 'using Color::e;' to code allow the use of 'cRed' and know this should be Color::e::cRed?

Answer (score 22):

FYI In C++0x there is a new syntax for cases like what you mentioned (see [C++0x wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B0x#Strongly_typed_enumerations))

```
enum class eColors { ... };
enum class eFeelings { ... };
```

Answer (score 14):

I've hybridized the preceding answers to something like this:  (EDIT: This is only useful for pre- C++11. If you are using C++11, use `enum class`)

I've got one big header file that contains all my project enums, because these enums are shared between worker classes and it doesn't make sense to put the enums in the worker classes themselves.

The `struct` avoids the public: syntactic sugar, and the `typedef` lets you actually declare variables of these enums within other worker classes.

I don't think using a namespace helps at all.  Maybe this is because I'm a C# programmer, and there you *have* to use the enum type name when referring the values, so I'm used to it.

```
    struct KeySource {
        typedef enum { 
            None, 
            Efuse, 
            Bbram
        } Type;
    };

    struct Checksum {
        typedef enum {
            None =0,
            MD5 = 1,
            SHA1 = 2,
            SHA2 = 3
        } Type;
    };

    struct Encryption {
        typedef enum {
            Undetermined,
            None,
            AES
        } Type;
    };

    struct File {
        typedef enum {
            Unknown = 0,
            MCS,
            MEM,
            BIN,
            HEX
        } Type;
    };
```

...

```
class Worker {
    File::Type fileType;
    void DoIt() {
       switch(fileType) {
       case File::MCS: ... ;
       case File::MEM: ... ;
       case File::HEX: ... ;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

I would definitely avoid using a class for this; use a namespace instead. The question boils down to whether to use a namespace or to use unique ids for the enum values. Personally, I'd use a namespace so that my ids could be shorter and hopefully more self-explanatory. Then application code could use a 'using namespace' directive and make everything more readable.

From your example above:

```
using namespace Colors;

void setPenColor( const e c ) {
    switch (c) {
        default: assert(false);
        break; case cRed: //...
        break; case cBlue: //...
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you give a hint on _why_ you would prefer a namespace over a class?

Comment: @xtofl : you can't write 'using class Colors`

Comment: @MSalters: You also can't write `Colors someColor = Red;`, because namespace doesn't constitute a type. You would have to write `Colors::e someColor = Red;` instead, which is quite counter-intuitive.

Comment: @SasQ Wouldn't you have to use `Colors::e someColor` even with a `struct/class` if you wanted to use it in a `switch` statement? If you use an anonymous `enum` then the switch wouldn't be able to evaluate a `struct`.

Comment: Sorry, but `const e c` seems hardly readable to me :-) Don't do that. Using a namespace however, is fine.

Answer (score 8):

Advantage of using a class is that you can build a full-fledged class on top of it.

```
#include <cassert>

class Color
{
public:
    typedef enum
    {
        Red,
        Blue,
        Green,
        Yellow
    } enum_type;

private:
    enum_type _val;

public:
    Color(enum_type val = Blue)
        : _val(val)
    {
        assert(val <= Yellow);
    }

    operator enum_type() const
    {
        return _val;
    }
};

void SetPenColor(const Color c)
{
    switch (c)
    {
        case Color::Red:
            // ...
            break;
    }
}
```

As the above example shows, by using a class you can:

1. prohibit (sadly, not compile-time) C++ from allowing a cast from invalid value,
2. set a (non-zero) default for newly-created enums,
3. add further methods, like for returning a string representation of a choice.

Just note that you need to declare `operator enum_type()` so that C++ would know how to convert your class into underlying enum. Otherwise, you won't be able to pass the type to a `switch` statement.

Comment: Is this solution somehow related to what is shown here?: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Type_Safe_Enum I'm thinking about how to make it a template that I don't have to rewrite this pattern every time I need to use it.

Comment: @SasQ: it seems similar, yes. That's probably the same idea. However, I'm not sure if a template is beneficial unless you're adding a lot of 'common' methods in there.

Comment: 1. Not really true. You can have compile time check that the enum is valid, via const_expr, or via private constructor for an int.

Answer (score 7):

An difference between using a class or a namespace is that the class cannot be reopened like a namespace can.  This avoids the possibility that the namespace might be abused in the future, but there is also the problem that you cannot add to the set of enumerations either.

A possible benefit for using a class, is that they can be used as template type arguments, which is not the case for namespaces:

```
class Colors {
public:
  enum TYPE {
    Red,
    Green,
    Blue
  };
};

template <typename T> void foo (T t) {
  typedef typename T::TYPE EnumType;
  // ...
}
```

Personally, I'm not a fan of *using*, and I prefer the fully qualified names, so I don't really see that as a plus for namespaces.  However, this is probably not the most important decision that you'll make in your project!

Comment: Not reopening classes is also a potential disadvantage. The list of colours is not finite either.

Comment: I think not repoening a class is a potential advantage. If I want more colors, I would just recompile the class with more colors. If I cannot do this (say I don't have the code), then I don't want to touch it in any case.

Comment: @MSalters: No possibility to reopen a class is not only not a disadvantage, but also a safety tool. Because when it'd be possible to reopen a class and add some values to the enum, it could break other library code which already depends on that enum and knows only the old set of values. It would then happily accept those new values, but break at runtime from not knowing what to do with them. Remember Open-Closed Principle: Class should be closed for *modifying*, but open for *extending*. By extending I mean not adding to the existing code, but wrapping over it with the new code (eg. deriving).

Comment: So when you want to extend the enum, you should make it a new type derived from the first (if only it were easily possible in C++... ;/ ). Then it could be safely used by the new code which understands those new values, but only the old values would be accepted (by converting them down) by the old code. They shouldn't accept any one from those new values as being of the wrong type (the extended one). Only the old values they understand are accepted as being of the correct (base) type (and accidentally also being of the new type, so it could be accepted by new code as well).

Answer (score 5):

Since enums are scoped to their enclosing scope, it's probably best to wrap them in *something* to avoid polluting the global namespace and to help avoid name collisions.  I prefer a namespace to class simply because `namespace` feels like a bag of holding, whereas `class` feels like a robust object (cf. the `struct` vs. `class` debate).  A possible benefit to a namespace is that it can be extended later - useful if you're dealing with third-party code that you cannot modify.

This is all moot of course when we get enum classes with C++0x.

Comment: enum classes... need to look that up!

Answer (score 3):

I also tend to wrap my enums in classes.

As signaled by Richard Corden, the benefit of a class is that it is a type in the c++ sense and so you can use it with templates.

I have special toolbox::Enum class for my needs that I specialize for every templates which provides basic functions (mainly: mapping an enum value to a std::string so that I/O are easier to read).

My little template also has the added benefit of really checking for the allowed values. The compiler is kind of lax on checking if the value really is in the enum:

```
typedef enum { False: 0, True: 2 } boolean;
   // The classic enum you don't want to see around your code ;)

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  boolean x = static_cast<boolean>(1);
  return (x == False || x == True) ? 0 : 1;
} // main
```

It always bothered me that the compiler will not catch this, since you are left with an enum value that has no sense (and that you won't expect).

Similarly:

```
typedef enum { Zero: 0, One: 1, Two: 2 } example;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  example y = static_cast<example>(3);
  return (y == Zero || y == One || y == Two) ? 0 : 1;
} // main
```

Once again main will return an error.

The problem is that the compiler will fit the enum in the smallest representation available (here we need 2 bits) and that everything that fits in this representation is considered a valid value.

There is also the problem that sometimes you'd rather have a loop on the possible values instead of a switch so that you don't have to modify all you switches each time you add a value to the enum.

All in all my little helper really ease things for my enums (of course, it adds some overhead) and it is only possible because I nest each enum in its own struct :)

Comment: Interesting.  Do you mind sharing the definition of your Enum class?