# Switch statement doesn't work with enum (C++)

Tags: c++, enums, switch-statement

```
enum Maximum_Value{
    MAXIMUM_VALUE_1 = 0,
    MAXIMUM_VALUE_7 = 1,
    MAXIMUM_VALUE_15 = 2,
    MAXIMUM_VALUE_26 = 3,
    MAXIMUM_VALUE_34 = 4
};

int value_from_function = functionetc();

switch(value_from_function){
    MAXIMUM_VALUE_1: printf("MAXIMUM_VALUE_1 :%x\n",value_from_function); break;
    MAXIMUM_VALUE_7: printf("MAXIMUM_VALUE_7 :%x\n",value_from_function); break;
    MAXIMUM_VALUE_15: printf("MAXIMUM_VALUE_15 %x\n",value_from_function); break;
    MAXIMUM_VALUE_26: printf("MAXIMUM_VALUE_26 %x\n",value_from_function); break;
    MAXIMUM_VALUE_34: printf("MAXIMUM_VALUE_34 %x\n",value_from_function); break;  
    default: printf("default :%x\n",value_from_function);
 }
```

The code above always seems to hit the default statement, printing "default :0" even though that should hit MAXIMUM_VALUE_1.

I've tried casting the variable in switch to no effect

I guess I should save the return value into a variable of type "Maximum_Value", but why doesn't the code work anyway?

Edit: Thanks for pointing out the awfully stupid mistake everyone :P. The root of the problem was copying coding from systemverilog, which uses 'case' as a keyword instead of 'switch', and doesn't require 'case' at the start of each case

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3019153/how-do-i-use-an-enum-value-on-a-switch-statement-in-c).

Comment: There seems to be no `case` in your `switch`??

Comment: you are missing the `case` keyword before every label!

Comment: Not a duplicate, just even more stupid :P

Comment: Shame I can't just delete this, as it is a simple typo not an important question

Comment: If it makes you feel any better - your question helped today. I made the same mistake and felt just as stupid! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Enumerators aren't labels but `switch` statements jump to labels. You use `case` to create a label `switch` statements can jump to:

```
case MAXIMUM_VALUE_1: ...; break;
```

Comment: Assuming this *did* compile without errors. Did the compiler see these lines `MAXIMUM_VALUE_1:` as a simple line label, then? Are variable names and/or enum members even allowed as labels?

Comment: @Jongware: Well, the code does compile but the switch statement doesn't have any reason to jump to the respective labels. You could jump into the middle of the `switch` statement using `goto MAXIMUM_VALUE_15;`, though.

Answer (score 4):

Add case keyword then it will work.

```
case MAXIMUM_VALUE_1: printf("MAXIMUM_VALUE_1 :%x\n",value_from_function); break;
case MAXIMUM_VALUE_7: printf("MAXIMUM_VALUE_7 :%x\n",value_from_function); break;
case MAXIMUM_VALUE_15: printf("MAXIMUM_VALUE_15 %x\n",value_from_function); break;
case MAXIMUM_VALUE_26: printf("MAXIMUM_VALUE_26 %x\n",value_from_function); break;
case MAXIMUM_VALUE_34: printf("MAXIMUM_VALUE_34 %x\n",value_from_function); break;  
default: printf("default :%x\n",value_from_function);
```

Answer (score 1):

you are missing the `case` keyword before every label!

syntax of switch case is-

```
switch(type){
case type1: ....; break;
case type2: ....; break;
......
default: .....;
}
```