# How to make a function that receives an enum

Tags: c++, function, enums

```
class Shapemaker
{
public:
  static Shape * shapeCreate(CDrawView::shape sh);
};
```

My enum on my CDrawView class is

```
enum shape{line, rect, elli};
shape current_shape;
```

when i call `Shapemaker::shapeCreate(current_shape)` on  I get error c2653`CDrawView` : is not a class or namespace name on `shapemaker.h`

Comment: use `void function (int);` or `void function (nameoftheClass::Color);`

Comment: i tried to pass the color variable enum, but it gives me a compile error saying that the "nameoftheclass" is not a class or namespace

Comment: can you show us the class that contains the enum? include any namespace or class it may be wrapped in.

Comment: i added the code to it @andre

Comment: @user2221404: nono, we want to see either `nameoftheClass` or `CDrawView`.

Comment: Show us `shapemaker.h` and `CDrawView.h`. _All_ of their code.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15691915/factory-c-issues

it's way too long. ShapeMaker is just what i have there but if you want to check CDrawView go to the link i sent you

Comment: This may be an include issue. in `shapemaker.h` did you include `CDrawView.h` ?

Comment: yes @andre it is included

Answer (score 1):

This is probably the most plain thing to do:

```
class Shapemaker{
    public:
    enum Color { //your colors here }
};

class Otherclass{
    void fun(Shapemaker::Color);
};
```

Now if your compiler does not recognize Shapemaker as a class name, that makes me think you didn't include its header file before declaring Otherclass.

Comment: but when i call fun() what goes inside it. the color red, yellow or fun(red) or an instance of the enum Color. fun(color);

Comment: you can both use
fun(Color(red));
or
Color mycolor; fun(mycolor);

Answer (score 0):

If it's an `enum` member of the other class, then you can reference it as `nameoftheClass::Color`, but it'd have to be publicly-visible:

```
void function(nameoftheClass:Color input);
```

Comment: i try to do that, but when i pass the enum i get a message saying that the class is not a class or a namespace

Comment: "nameoftheclass" is not a class or namespace.
i passed the parameter as function(nameofenum) and it gives me that

Comment: Perhaps, then you could add the full declaration of the class where the `enum` is defined, and we can probably be more help

Comment: i added the full declaration of whats happening to me @dan.lecocq

Answer (score 0):

Say you have as follows:

```
class C {
    public:
        enum E {
            HERP,
            DERP
        };
 };
```

A function taking that enum would look like:

```
void foo(C::E e) {
   // do stuff with e
}
```

Comment: say i declare E as em.
when i do foo(em) it says that class C is not a namespace or class when i try to compile

Answer (score 0):

It's all a matter of namespace in the end. Have a look at the answers to this question too, definitively you must not use the keyword `enum` in the function's parameter list, use directly the enum name with the appropriate namespace.

[namespaces for enum types - best practices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/482745/namespaces-for-enum-types-best-practices)

Comment: the problem is that when i try to call the function i keep getting an error saying that the class is not a class or namespace

Comment: can you check the new edit that i have made, if you don't mind and if you know why it doesn't work would you mind explaining it?

Comment: I assume you forgot to include the header for `CDrawView` in the file where you are using the static method.

Answer (score 0):

> i tried to pass the color variable enum, but it gives me a compile error saying that the "nameoftheclass" is not a class or namespace

You need to have a declaration placed before you use it, meaning you need proper header files:

**MyClass.h**

```
class MyClass {
    public:
        enum Color {
            Red,
            Green,
            Blue
        };
};
```

**MyOtherClass.h**

```
#include "MyClass.h" // This is required.

// Now you can use MyClass::Color freely.
```

Comment: can you check the new edits that i have added @Magtheridon96. I am including CDrawView.h at the top