# Switches in C++

Tags: c++

I am new to C++ and programming in general and was trying to figure out a way to create a switch in C++ to trigger when a number entered is divisible by 3, by 5, and by both 3 and 5. Here is what I have so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int number;

    cout << "Please input a number and then press the enter key" << endl;
    cin >> number;

    switch (number){
    case "/3":
        cout << "Fizz" << endl;
        break;
    case "/5":
        cout << "Buzz" << endl;
        break;
    case "/3" "/5":
        cout << "FizzBuzz" << endl;
        break;
    default:
        cout << "Please select another number." << endl;
    }

}
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: You need to read some basic C/C++ book. `switch` is only able to check for a perfect match.

Comment: Be nice. Check out this link, it may help: http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/modulus.html

Comment: Well, first up, you cannot switch on a string.

Comment: Secondly, you're not actually checking if they are divisible. Why would you think that "/3" would be a check?

Comment: @Sean "  you cannot switch on a string " - you can, if you map the enum element to a string.

Comment: @M010 - Maybe you'd like to elaborate?

Comment: #include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
enum seasons { Winter , Autumn };
seasons getStringFromEnum(string inputSeason)
{
 map<string, seasons> seasonMap;
 seasonMap["SeasonWinter"] = seasons::Winter;
 seasonMap["SeasonAutumn"] = seasons::Autumn;
 return seasonMap[inputSeason];
}
void main(){
 std::string input = "SeasonWinter";
 seasons season = getStringFromEnum(input);
 switch(season){
 case seasons::Winter:
  cout << " Winter case" << endl ;
  break;
 case seasons::Autumn:
  cout << "Autumn case" << endl;
  break;}
} //  winter case

Comment: http://pastebin.com/db67wzhx

Comment: @M010 - right, so like I said, you cannot switch on a string.

Answer (score 9):

In C++ the `switch` labels *must* be compile-time evaluable constant expressions that are integral types.

"/3", for example, is a string literal and so does not fit that requirement.

In this case, use `number % 3 == 0` to test for divisibility by 3, and so on and use an `if`, `else` block:

```
if (number % 15 == 0){
    /*FizzBuzz - do this one first as my `if` block is not mutually exclusive*/
} else if (number % 3 == 0){
    /*Fizz*/
} else if (number % 5 == 0){
    /*Buzz*/
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I know it was an amateur question, and I was between using if statements and a switch. Visual Studio kept giving an error saying that my initial expression needed to be a constant. In any case thank you so much again! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `if else`.

```
int remainder1 = 0, remainder2 = 0;
remainder1 = number % 3;
remainder2 = number % 5;

if(remainder1 == 0 && remainder2 ==0) // both
       cout<<"FizzBuzz"<<'\n';
else if(remainder1 == 0)  // number can be divided by 3
       cout<<"Fizz"<<'\n';
else if(remainder2 == 0) // number can be divided by 5
       cout<<"Buzz\n";
else   // neither
       cout<<"......"<<'\n';
```

BTW,  you do have to read the **basic book** about C++.

here, you can know more about [switch](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/switch)

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to do with switch, here is a method, but is not nice. The easiest way is how Bathsheba said.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

enum class divided { DivideBy3  , DivideBy5 , DivideBy3and5 }; // "strong enum" 

// enum class divided { DivideBy3  , DivideBy5 , DivideBy3and5 }; //also good but can be unsafe
divided getCase(int number)
{
  divided div;

  if(number%3 == 0)
        div = divided::DivideBy3;
  if(number%5 == 0)
        div = divided::DivideBy5;
  if(number%3 ==0 && number%5 == 0)
        div = divided::DivideBy3and5;

  return div;
}

int main()
{
  int numberIn;

  cout << "Please input a number and then press the enter key" << endl;
  cin >> numberIn;

  divided number =  getCase(numberIn);

  switch (number)
  {
  case divided::DivideBy3:
      cout << "Fizz" << endl;
    break;
  case divided::DivideBy5:
      cout << "Buzz" << endl;
    break;
  case divided::DivideBy3and5:
      cout << "FizzBuzz" << endl;
    break;
  default:
      cout << "Please select another number." << endl;
   }

}
```

look at this for [enum vs class enum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18335861/why-is-enum-class-preferred-over-plain-enum). Keep going.