# Issue with initializer list for vector of an enum class

Tags: c++, vector, enums

I have an enum, and a couple of vectors of some of the contents of the enum.  I want to change the enum to an enum class, for type safety, but I'm getting errors.  Consider the following snippet:

```
#include <vector>

enum Colour {
        red,
        green,
        blue
};

int main() {
        const std::vector<Colour> something { red, green };
        return 0;
}
```

It works fine.  However, if I change the enum to an enum class, I get errors such as `error: ‘green’ was not declared in this scope`.  What can I do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `Color::green` for enum classes.

Comment: So I have to do that every time I refer to an instance of an enum class?  I'm starting to think they're not really worth it.

Comment: Why, It makes the code more readable? And enum class is safer than plain enums btw.

Comment: It seems more readable to me to say `thecolour = red` than `thecolour = Colour::red`.  `Colour::` looks like useless junk.

Comment: red might be defined elsewhere, like in an external library. It's a trade off, a bit more typing for some type safety.

Comment: But whatever variable you're using will already be of type `Colour`, so it *can't* be assigned to something of another type, right?

Comment: @Elronnd, No, plain enums in c++ are just numbers. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18335861/why-is-enum-class-preferred-over-plain-enum