# Remove enum visibility in C++

Tags: c++

How can I force all enums to have their own namespace?

I have multiple enums with members that have the same name, and want them to be accessed through the enum namespace,

for example

```
enum X {b, a};
enum Y {a, b};
```

The above code won't compile because a is either X::a or Y::a

How can I make it so that a can never be used unless the client specifies X::A or Y::A, so it compiles?

Comment: `enum class` in C++11 and beyond.

Comment: if c++11 use enum class.

Comment: use an enum class

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is enum class preferred over plain enum?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18335861/why-is-enum-class-preferred-over-plain-enum)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
enum class X {b, a};
enum class Y {a, b};
```

this does what you want, and also disables a bunch of implicit conversion to integral types that enums do.

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to actually use *real* namespaces for this:

```
#include <iostream>

namespace X { enum X {b = 1, a = 2}; }
namespace Y { enum Y {a = 3, b = 4}; }

int main (void) {
    std::cout << X::a << std::endl;          // use value.
    std::cout << sizeof(Y::Y) << std::endl;  // use type.
    Y::Y yy = Y::b;                          // set variable.

    return 0;
}
```

You can see three likely operations (using the values directly, using the type, and declaring/setting variables) in the respective lines of `main()`.