# Avoid cast while comparing enum class with int

Tags: c++, c++11, enums, casting

I finally [convinced](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18335861/why-is-enum-class-preferred-over-plain-enum) my co-worker to use `enum class` instead of the old `enum`.

However, when comparing `int` to a enum class value a cast is necessary now. At least IntelliSense says so:

[image]

Because of that unecessary cast (since the underlying type is int) she now wants to stay with the old enum...

Please help me out with arguments in that discussion. Maybe there is a technical way to avoid the cast?

Comment: The explicit cast is a good thing. `int` is not `Colors`. If you want to avoid the cast, don't have an `int` in the first place.

Comment: Please post the actual code, not a picture of the code. TIA.

Comment: Also note that IntelliSense is not a compiler. Don't rely on its messages, but on the errors of the compiler you're using. It's wrong sometimes.

Comment: Somewhere on SO I saw an overload of the `operator+` to return an int from the enum class that I found reasonable.

Comment: The whole point of using `enum class` is to stop the implicit conversion during comparisons.  If you want to subvert that then you might as well just go back to using an `enum`.

Comment: [Here is an answer that I couldn't post](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2cd734a44bc1b704).

Comment: [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cZ3TNrRzHfM) explain how to use `enum class` as bit field. I don't think you can use it in your example but it might be useful.

Answer (score 6):

Either you want your enum values to be default-convertible to and from integers, or you don't.

Choose plain `enum` if your values represent things that are number-like.

Choose `enum class` if your values aren't tied to their integer representations.

If you're using `enum class`, then you shouldn't need to compare against `int` values; if you do, then the explicit cast draws attention to the suspect code; that's a Good Thing.

Comment: I was under the impression that `enum class` exists to reduce namespace pollution, not because of some asinine strong typing nonsense.

Comment: There are other ways to reduce namespace pollution, but no other way to avoid implicit conversion.