# How are constant expressions dealt with in c++ enum?

Tags: c++, enums

What is the range of a c++ enum with a constant expression? This is my code

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    enum e3{min = -10, max = 100000};
    e3 x = e3(-1000);
    e3 y= e3(-100000912241);
    std::cout<<x<<" "<<y<<std::endl;
}
```

It outputs `-1000 -1216664433`

How is this happening?
Also, `The C++ programming language by Bjarne Stroustrup` specifies that the result of conversion of integral type to enumeration is undefined unless the value is the within the range of the enumeration. What is this range and how to calculate it?

Comment: I recommend not using enums values as integers. It is a bad design as this is not the purpose of usage of them. Maybe `struct` is a good replacement. That is why c++ prefers [enum class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18335861/why-is-enum-class-preferred-over-plain-enum)es over typical enums.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The range of an `enum` is the range of the underlying type. The compiler has probably selected an `int` as the underlying type of your `enum`.

It's allowed to do that since an `int` (assuming it's 32 bit on your platform) can contain all the explicit values you've given it.

You'll probably find that the type of `-100000912241` is a `long` or a `long long` on your platform (note there is no such thing as a negative literal in C++: `-100000912241` is the unary negation of the literal `100000912241`.). But `-100000912241` can't fit into that `int`, so the behaviour of your code is *undefined*.

If you want to inspect the underlying type of an `enum`, then use `std::underlying_type`.

Reference: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/underlying_type

Comment: It makes sense but what is the range of an enum? Is an enum supposed to accept all integral values or only values within a particular range based on its initialisation

Comment: @Krash: Added that to the answer.