# use of enumeration in a nested name specifier (compiler warning)

Tags: c++, enums

I have an enum:

```
enum eOperandType
{
    Int8,
    Int16,
    Int32,
    Float,
    Double
};
```

and a member function of the class 'Double'

```
eOperandType    Double::getType(void) const
{
        return (eOperandType::Double);
}
```

and it gives me a compiler warning about using enumeration in nested name specifier.

I also switched the  return line to: `return (Double);` but then it just gave me an error regarding an expected expression.

How do i resolve this?

---

edit: changing the line to `return (::Double);` did fix both the warning and the error. Could someone explain why this fixes it?

Comment: Why do you have the unnecessary parentheses around your return value? Why do you have `getType(void)`; that should be `getType()`.

Comment: `return (Double);` probably fails because it looks like a cast; `Double` there would be referring to your class `Double`

Comment: @Justin White spaces and new lines can also be unnecessary!

Comment: @TheoWalton Try not using `eOperandType::` before the enumeration value.

Comment: @Zingam Yes, but `return (...)` easily leads to bugs in some cases. Thus I claim it's best to avoid it entirely. And it's completely unneeded, even for readability

Comment: You might want to check out [`enum class`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18335861/1896169)

Comment: Your class and the enum value are both called `Double`

Comment: @Justin You may be right but I once read the opposite argumentation to your claim. My point is - the original question is not about style.

Comment: Please note that *"changing the line to `return (::Double);`"* doesn't really fix your code: https://ideone.com/PQFLJX You should use an enum class, a scoped enum or better, change the names.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Prior to C++11, you were not allowed to refer to enumerators as *`enum-name::enumerator`*. So `eOperandType::Double` is invalid if you're using an old compiler or haven't enabled C++11 mode. If you're using gcc or clang, pass the `-std=c++11` flag to the compiler.

If that's not an option, then change `return (Double);` to `return ::Double;`, or `return (::Double);` if you're fond of unnecessary parentheses. Without the `::`, `Double` refers to the name of the enclosing class. By adding the scope resolution operator, you're telling the compiler you're referring to `Double` in the global namespace, i.e. the enumerator.

The third option is to not give your class the same name as enumerators.

Comment: I don't think that changing the line to `return (::Double);`" would be enough: https://ideone.com/PQFLJX , but OP could limit the scope of the enum using a namespace: https://ideone.com/pAqw8b

Comment: @Bob__ The error in your example has nothing to do with the return statement, it's in the declaration of `a` within `main`. Since the code is using the same name for the class and enumerator, you must use an [elaborated type specifier](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/elaborated_type_specifier), `class Double a;` - https://ideone.com/Vss3OI

Comment: You are right and that's just a further reason to use different names.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to used scoped enumerations you need to make the enum:

```
enum struct eOperandType
```

(or"enum class")