# no type named on C++ enumeration

Tags: c++, templates, enums, compilation

I'm having this declaration of a "relation" class which requires to be initialized "relation_label" value.

```
namespace hr {
    class node;

    enum relation_label : uint8_t {
        HAS, CONTAINS, IS_PARALLEL, INCLUDES, IS, PART_OF, LEADS_TO, IN
    };


    template<typename N>
    class relation : public std::vector<N> {
    private:
        relation(const relation &) = default;

    public:
        const relation_label label;

        relation(relation_label l) : std::vector<N>(0) {
            this->label = l;
        };
    };
}
```

This code compiles, but making new instances of relation objects does not compile. For example, the error on:

```
relation<word *> includes(relation_label::INCLUDES);
```

is "No type named 'INCLUDES' in 'hr::relation_label'".

Any idea?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18335861/why-is-enum-class-preferred-over-plain-enum

Comment: You should initialize `label` member variable, since it is `const`.

Answer (score 1):

The error you're seeing could be caused by another error before that, which is:

`const` members must be initialized inline or with a member-init-list. In the body of the constructor they are already `const`.

Change

```
    relation(relation_label l) : std::vector<N>(0) {
        this->label = l;
    };
```

To

```
    relation(relation_label l) : std::vector<N>(0), label(l) {
    }
```

Also, I hope `word` is a type defined somewhere in your application.

---

**=== EDIT ===**

From the comment:

> "word" is defined like this:
>
> ```
> class word;
> class word_related : public named_node {
> public: relation<word*> includes(relation_label::INCLUDES);
> };
> ```

What does `relation<word*> includes(relation_label::INCLUDES)` mean? It looks like a definition of a member function `includes()`, but then `relation_label::INCLUDES` must be a type. Which it is not, obviously.

Maybe you meant

```
relation<word*> includes(relation_label lbl = relation_label::INCLUDES);
```

?

Comment: I did what you did. No change unfortunately. :( I also removed the "const" qualifier, but still no change. "word" is defined like this:    class word;

    class word_related : public named_node {

    public:
        relation<word *> includes(relation_label::INCLUDES);

Answer (score 0):

As you're trying to create a new instance of the relation object in the line yielding the compile error, try using bracket-initialization

```cpp
relation<word*> includes{relation_label::INCLUDES};
```

instead. When compiling your previous code

```cpp
class word_related : public named_node {
public: relation<word*> includes(relation_label::INCLUDES);
};
```

the compiler thinks you're about to declare a member function called `includes` of the class `named_node` (and therefore it expects the type of the function's parameter instead of a 'value'), instead of defining a default-initialized member variable.

This answer is supplemental to rustyx's answer, who addresses the most important point of the missing initialization of the const member variable.

The code can be found [here](https://godbolt.org/z/WvX8Ps), with the fix from rustyx's answer applied.