# C++ "Class Enum" Novice Problems

Tags: c++, class, enums

I'm starting learning to code in C++ (coming from VB.net) and i need some help in `enum class` usage.

I've done this simple code from a lerning exercise (originally divided in header.h and Exercise.cpp, but i putted it all together here):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#define BEGIN_WITH(x) { \
        auto &_ = x;
#define END_WITH() }

using namespace std;

enum class Gender { Male, Female };

struct PersonStruct {
    string _Name;
    string _SurName;
    int _Age;
    double _Heigth;
    Gender _Gender; };

class Person { public:
    string _Name{};
    string _SurName{};
    int _Age{};
    double _Heigth{};
    Gender _Gender{}; };


int ModifyPerson(Person& PassPersona, PersonStruct Attribute) {
    PassPersona._Name = Attribute._Name;
    PassPersona._SurName = Attribute._SurName;
    PassPersona._Heigth = Attribute._Heigth;
    PassPersona._Age = Attribute._Age;
    PassPersona._Gender = Attribute._Gender;

    return(0); }

int main() {    Person TestingPerson;

    BEGIN_WITH(TestingPerson)
    _._Age = 23;
    _._Gender = Gender::Male;
    _._Heigth = 1.94;
    _._Name = "John";
    _._SurName = "Smith";
    END_WITH()

    cout << "Person attributes: " << endl;
    cout << "Name: " << TestingPerson._Name << endl;
    cout << "Surname: " << TestingPerson._SurName << endl;
    cout << "Age: " << TestingPerson._Age << endl;
    cout << "Gender: " << TestingPerson._Gender << endl;
    cout << "Heigth: " << TestingPerson._Heigth << endl;
    cout << endl;

    ModifyPerson(TestingPerson, PersonStruct{ "Poca","Hontas",24,1.85,Gender::Female });

    cout << "New Person attributes: " << endl;
    cout << "Name: " << TestingPerson._Name << endl;
    cout << "Surname: " << TestingPerson._SurName << endl;
    cout << "Age: " << TestingPerson._Age << endl;
    cout << "Gender: " << TestingPerson._Gender << endl;
    cout << "Heigth: " << TestingPerson._Heigth << endl;

    return(0); }
```

I've made the structure in order to group all `Person` class parameters. Doing this i've learned that using `enum class` is more secure than `class`. But when i switched to `enum class` a lot of errors prompted on my code. I've solved almost all of them, except this:

```
cout << "Gender: " << TestingPerson._Gender << endl;
```

> Error code E0349 "no operator "<<" matches these operands"

I've searched around but i find no solution to this. Thanks in advance for your time! (any suggestion or recommendation on my code should be appreciated)

Comment: please create a [MRE]. I.e. remove all code not relevant to your problem `cout << "Gender: " << TestingPerson._Gender << endl;`

Comment: @bolov I know... but i potsed more code because i don't know where the error comes and maybe is from another part of it.

Comment: *Doing this i've learned that using enum class is more secure than class* 

Why?

Comment: Maybe you should explicitly convert your enum to int when using it in cout?

Comment: @Roy2511 The reason is before reading this post: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18335861/why-is-enum-class-preferred-over-plain-enum)

Comment: *Why is enum class preferred over plain enum?* vs *Doing this i've learned that using enum class is more secure than class* @IvanFont

Comment: Since it's not implicitly convertible to `int`, I wouldn't expect there to be an existing overload of `operator<<` that would handle it.  You need to either convert to a type that has an existing overload, or provide your own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<<` operator is not defined for class `Gender` because it's your own class. You'll need to overload it. [More info here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/standard-library/overloading-the-output-operator-for-your-own-classes?view=vs-2019)

```
enum class Gender
{
  male,
  female
};

ostream& operator<< (ostream & os, const Gender & g)
{
  switch(g)
  {
      case Gender::male: os << "Male"; return os;
      case Gender::female: os << "Female"; return os;
  }
  return os;
};
```

Comment: Thanks, all working now! in the same way, if i use `os << static_cast<std::underlying_type<Gender>::type>(obj)` i get the integer value from enum class. I still don't get it at 100%, but thanks!