# What's the difference between typedef enum and enum class?

Tags: c++, enums, typedef, enum-class

I'm probably missing something but I'm working with a code base that uses a lot of

```
typedef enum foo
{
    ....
} foo;
```

Is this just the same as an enum class but not strongly typed?

Comment: No, this is a regular enum. This `typedef` does nothing useful in C++ (but did something useful in C)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18335861/why-is-enum-class-preferred-over-plain-enum It should answer your question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is enum class preferred over plain enum?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18335861/why-is-enum-class-preferred-over-plain-enum)

Answer (score 8):

Using `typedef enum` does something different than `enum class`.

The use of `typedef enum`, as @UnholySheep mentioned in the comments, is mostly a C idiom that isn't needed in C++. In C, if you declared an `enum` like this:

```
enum Ghost {
    Blinky,
    Pinky,
    Inky,
    Clyde
};
```

then to declare a variable of type `Ghost`, you'd have to say

```
enum Ghost oneGhost;
```

The use of "`enum`" here could be a bit annoying, so a pattern emerged of writing out the `enum` declaration as

```
typedef enum Ghost {
    Blinky,
    Winky,
    Pinky,
    Clyde
} Ghost;
```

This says "there's a type called `enum Ghost` defined as usual, but you can just call it `Ghost` for short. That way, in C, you could write

```
Ghost myGhost;
```

and have everything you need.

However, C++ dropped the requirement to use `enum` this way. If you have a `Ghost` defined using the first (`typedef`-free) version of the code, you could just say `Ghost myGhost;` just fine. In that sense, there's not much reason to use `typedef enum` in C++.

This is quite different than `enum class`. In C++, `enum class` has the advantage that the constants defined in the enumeration don't end up as part of the namespace in which the `enum` was defined, and you can't implicitly convert from an `enum class` to an integer type. In that sense, `enum class` is mostly about type safety and making it hard to make mistakes with an `enum`.

Hope this helps!