# Which to prefer? An enum class, or a nested unnamed enum type?

Tags: c++, c++11, enums, difference, strong-typing

```
enum Color1 { red, blue, green }; // ok
// enum Color2 { red, blue, green }; // error, enum conflicts

struct Color3
{
    enum { red, blue, green }; // ok, no conflicts
};

enum class Color4 { red, blue, green }; // ok, no conflicts
```

1. `Color1` and `Color2` are both weak typing.
2. `Color3` and `Color4` are both strong typing.

My questions are:

**1. Is there any difference between `Color3` and `Color4`?**

**2. Which to prefer? `Color3` or `Color4`? Why?**

Comment: For `Color1`, the outer class doesn't really matter, `red` is just a plain `enum`. So you are really asking about the difference between an `enum` and an `enum class`, and yes, there are differences between them. Both ways work, so I'm voting to close this as opinion-based, unless you make it more focused about a real technical issue.

Comment: About the strong typing, try `std::cout << 42 + Color1::red << '\n';` and then with `Color2::red`. Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18335861/why-is-enum-class-preferred-over-plain-enum

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *`Color3` and `Color4` are both strong typing*

No. Try this:

```
int x = Color3::red; // ok
int y = Color4::red; // error: cannot convert from 'Color4' to 'int'
```

The legacy enum is implicitly convertible to an integer, but `enum class` is it's own type.

As to which to prefer, refer to [Why is enum class preferred over plain enum?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18335861/why-is-enum-class-preferred-over-plain-enum)