# Non-type parametric template function, error: reference to non-static member function must be called

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

I am trying to use a not-type parametric template function as a member of a class and am running into errors. Below is a minimum working example

```
#include <iostream>

enum Mode {ka, kb, kab};

class Foo {
  public:
    Foo(const double& x = 1.0, const Mode& y = ka) : x_(x), y_(y) {;}

    Mode get() const{
      return y_;
    }
    template<Mode mode> double FooFunc();

  private:
    double x_;
    Mode y_;
};

template<> double Foo::FooFunc<ka>() {
  return 1/x_;
}

template<> double Foo::FooFunc<kb>() {
  return 1/x_/x_;
}

template<> double Foo::FooFunc<kab>() {
  return 1/x_/x_/x_;
}

int main() {
  Foo foo1(2, ka), foo2(2, kb), foo3(2, kab);

  std::cout << "foo1 function result: " << foo1.FooFunc<foo1.get()> << "\n";
  std::cout << "foo2 function result: " << foo2.FooFunc<foo2.get()> << "\n";                                                                                                                                                                                                  
  std::cout << "foo3 function result: " << foo3.FooFunc<foo3.get()> << "\n";

  return 0;
}
```

I am compiling this with clang as follows `c++ foo.cpp -o foo -O3 -std=c++11`. This results in the following errors and I am not sure what the issue is. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
foo.cpp:34:48: error: reference to non-static member function must be called
        std::cout << "foo1 function result: " << foo1.FooFunc<foo1.get()> << "\n";
                                                 ~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
foo.cpp:12:30: note: possible target for call
                template<Mode mode> double FooFunc();
                                           ^
foo.cpp:35:48: error: reference to non-static member function must be called
        std::cout << "foo2 function result: " << foo2.FooFunc<foo2.get()> << "\n";
                                                 ~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
foo.cpp:12:30: note: possible target for call
                template<Mode mode> double FooFunc();
                                           ^
foo.cpp:36:48: error: reference to non-static member function must be called
        std::cout << "foo3 function result: " << foo3.FooFunc<foo3.get()> << "\n";
                                                 ~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
foo.cpp:12:30: note: possible target for call
                template<Mode mode> double FooFunc();
                                           ^
3 errors generated.
```

Comment: a template argument must be a compile-time constant, `foo1.get()` is not.

Comment: @RedFog, thank you. How could I modify such that it could be used at run-time without the use of either if else or switch case blocks?

Comment: to choose a compile-time branch by a runtime result, the only way is to use `switch` statement (including `if`-`else` statement), mapping table or virtual function. in your case, `switch` statement is definitely better.

Comment: Also, FYI, no need to put a `;` into an empty function or method, simply `{}` will do.  =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your code is that a **template argument has to be compile-time constant**. For a function call this means it has to be `constexpr` while for a class method this means it has to be `static`.

You have only two options:

- Either you leave the configuration of the `Mode` to run-time and allow the user to potentially re-configuring the `Mode`. For this you will have to introduce an **`if`/`else` or `switch` statement** inside the function.

  ```
  class Foo {
    public:
      constexpr Foo(double const x = 1.0, Mode const y = Mode::ka) noexcept
        : x_{x}, y_{y} {
        return;
      }
      Mode get() const noexcept {
        return y_;
      }
      double FooFunc() const {
        switch (y_) {
          case Mode::ka: 
            return 1.0/x_;
          case Mode::kb:
            return 1.0/x_/x_;
          case Mode::kab:
            return 1.0/x_/x_/x_;
          default:
            // Throw error
        }
      }
    private:
      double x_;
      Mode y_;
  };
  ```
- If you do not plan to give the user the possibility to change the `Mode` on the fly you might make it a **class template** and specialise the corresponding function. This way there is though no possibility to change the mode on the fly.

  ```
  template <Mode M = Mode::ka>
  class Foo {
    public:
      constexpr Foo(double const x = 1.0) noexcept
        : x_(x) {
        return;
      }
      static constexpr Mode get() noexcept {
        return M;
      }
      double FooFunc() const noexcept;
    private:
      double x_;
      Mode y_;
  };

  template<>
  inline double Foo<Mode::ka>::FooFunc() const noexcept {
    return 1.0/x_;
  }
  template<>
  inline double Foo<Mode::kb>::FooFunc() const noexcept {
    return 1.0/x_/x_;
  }
  template<>
  inline double Foo<Mode::kab>::FooFunc() const noexcept {
    return 1.0/x_/x_/x_;
  }
  ```

Comment: Thank you for a helpful and detailed answer! I ended up using template specializations. I was trying to avoid if else/switch statements in a for loop.

Comment: @bhache You are welcome! Another thing that I noticed is that you used a plain enum `enum Mode` instead of a scoped enum `enum class Mode`. Generally the latter should be preferred that is why I used `Mode::kab` instead of `kab` only. See e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18335862/9938686) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

With `constexpr`, you might do:

```
enum Mode {ka, kb, kab};

class Foo {
public:
    constexpr Foo(const double& x = 1.0, const Mode& y = ka) : x_(x), y_(y) {}

    constexpr Mode get() const{
      return y_;
    }
    template<Mode mode> constexpr double FooFunc() const;

private:
    double x_;
    Mode y_;
};

template<> constexpr double Foo::FooFunc<ka>() const {
  return 1/x_;
}

template<> constexpr double Foo::FooFunc<kb>() const {
  return 1/x_/x_;
}

template<> constexpr double Foo::FooFunc<kab>() const {
  return 1/x_/x_/x_;
}

int main() {
  constexpr Foo foo1(2, ka), foo2(2, kb), foo3(2, kab);

  std::cout << "foo1 function result: " << foo1.FooFunc<foo1.get()>() << "\n";
  std::cout << "foo2 function result: " << foo2.FooFunc<foo2.get()>() << "\n";
  std::cout << "foo3 function result: " << foo3.FooFunc<foo3.get()>() << "\n";
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ca465b44da72e718)