# Define type of variable with its own constant values

Tags: c++, class, types, typedef

I want to create a new type of variable which has his own constant values. So I want to do something likes this: (This is a not working example to explain the idea)

```
class Variabletype {
public:
 static const uint8_t Option1 = 0;
 static const uint8_t Option2 = 1;
};

typedef const uint8_t Variabletype;

int main() {
    Variabletype vt = Variabletype::Option1;
    
    if (vt == Variabletype::Option1)
        printf("Option 1\n");
    else
        printf("Option 2\n");
        
    return 0;
}
```

I can't typedef the name `Variabletype` after declaring it as a class, but I hope it makes clear, what my intention is? The benefit of this idea would be finding directly the possible values of the variable, `vt`. I also don't want to spam my global space with constants, and I can not set `vt` to impossible values.

So is something like this possible? I already searched a lot but didn't find any solution.

Comment: You seem to want an `enum` variable or an `enum class`.

Comment: @AdrianMole Thank you very much, this is what I searched for! So I have something like this:
enum class Variabletype {Option1, Option2};

Comment: I assumed there would already be a canonical duplicate for this problem. I looked but did not find one, so I posted an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are looking for is an [*enumeration type*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum) – designed specifically for the purpose you outline. Although you *can* use a plain, 'C-style' `enum`, a more modern, C++ approach is to use a so-called "scoped enum"; see: [Why is enum class preferred over plain enum?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18335861/10871073)

Here's a possible implementation of your code using such a `enum class` definition:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

enum class Variabletype : uint8_t { // You can specify the underlying type after the ":"
    Option1 = 0, // You can specify any 'actual' values you like ...
    Option2 = 1, // ... but the default uses values of 0, 1, 2 anyway
};

int main()
{
    Variabletype vt = Variabletype::Option1;

    if (vt == Variabletype::Option1)
        std::cout << "Option 1" << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "Option 2" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```