# How to use an enum attribute of a class for an argument of a setter function for that class?

Tags: c++

I have a class method that needs to know the value of a variable named `mode` which takes the values 1 an 0 and is a private attribute of the class. I want to write a setter function that can change `mode` to 1 or 0. However, I must use an enum to determine the new value that I should set `mode` to: `enum sequence {error=0,active =1};` I want sequence to be an attribute (I was hoping to make it private) of the class. How can I write a setter function that takes as input `active` or `error` and sets the value of mode accordingly. Here is the basic structure of my code:

```
#include <iostream>
class Blink{

public:

  void setter(...){
  
     
}
  
private:()
  int mode = 0;
  enum sequence {error = 0, active = 1};

};
Blink b;
int main() {
   
  b.setter(active);
  
  
}
```

PS: I'm having a hard time coming up with a good title for this question, suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: Since the enumeration is `private`, you can't use it from "outside the class". If you make it `public` then you use it with the scope operator `::`, as in `Blink::active`.

Comment: Maybe my title was misleading but I was hoping to keep sequence private and only change it through the setter method. I wouldn't be changing it outside of the scope of the class.

Comment: Your call to the setter in `main()` is already outside the scope of the class.

Comment: One option would be to have *two* setters, `setActive()` and `setError()`. There is absolutely no rule that we must have one setter per member variable. (Often *none* is the correct number :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's pretty straight forward. This is how I would do it in C++11 and above:

```cpp
class Blink {

public:
  enum class Sequence { Error, Active };
  
  void setter(Sequence s) {
    if (s == Sequence::Active) {
      mode = 1;
    } else {
      mode = 0;
    }
  }
  
private:
  int mode = 0;
};

Blink b;

int main() {
  b.setter(Blink::Sequence::Active);
}
```

The main difference is that `Sequence` is declared publicly. Note that `mode` is still a private variable so there is no harm. Sequence becomes part of the public interface because it needs to be understood from outside.

The second change is that I use `enum class`. Yes, you could also use a plain enum that implicitely casts to the integer, but see [Why is enum class preferred over plain enum?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18335861/why-is-enum-class-preferred-over-plain-enum)
In this simple example, I would instead use private member `Sequence mode = Sequence::Error;` instead of `int mode = 0;`.