# enum class nested in a class compiles on Linux, but not MacOS?

Tags: c++, enums, compiler-errors, g++, enum-class

I wrote a basic program to show the issue I'm dealing with.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class SomeClass {
    private:

    public:
    enum class SomeEnum : int {a, b, c};

    void print() {
        cout << "test";
    }
};

int main() {
    SomeClass::SomeEnum test1 = SomeClass::SomeEnum::a;
    SomeClass::SomeEnum test2 = SomeClass::SomeEnum::b;
    SomeClass::SomeEnum test3 = SomeClass::SomeEnum::c;
}
```

Basically, there's an enum class that is nested within another class. When I try compiling this on Linux, I have no problem. Compiling this on MacOS throws this at me:

```
test.cpp:8:10: warning: scoped enumerations are a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
    enum class SomeEnum : int {a, b, c};
         ^
test.cpp:8:10: error: reference to enumeration must use 'enum' not 'enum class' [-Welaborated-enum-class]
    enum class SomeEnum : int {a, b, c};
         ^~~~~~
test.cpp:8:31: error: expected '(' for function-style cast or type construction
    enum class SomeEnum : int {a, b, c};
                          ~~~ ^
test.cpp:16:5: error: no type named 'SomeEnum' in 'SomeClass'; did you mean simply 'SomeEnum'?
    SomeClass::SomeEnum test1 = SomeClass::SomeEnum::a;
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    SomeEnum
test.cpp:8:16: note: 'SomeEnum' declared here
    enum class SomeEnum : int {a, b, c};
               ^
test.cpp:16:44: error: 'SomeEnum' is not a class, namespace, or enumeration
    SomeClass::SomeEnum test1 = SomeClass::SomeEnum::a;
                                           ^
test.cpp:17:25: error: use of undeclared identifier 'test2'; did you mean 'test1'?
    SomeClass::SomeEnum test2 = SomeClass::SomeEnum::b;
                        ^~~~~
                        test1
test.cpp:16:25: note: 'test1' declared here
    SomeClass::SomeEnum test1 = SomeClass::SomeEnum::a;
                        ^
test.cpp:17:24: error: expected ';' after expression
    SomeClass::SomeEnum test2 = SomeClass::SomeEnum::b;
                       ^
                       ;
test.cpp:17:16: error: no member named 'SomeEnum' in 'SomeClass'
    SomeClass::SomeEnum test2 = SomeClass::SomeEnum::b;
    ~~~~~~~~~~~^
test.cpp:17:44: error: 'SomeEnum' is not a class, namespace, or enumeration
    SomeClass::SomeEnum test2 = SomeClass::SomeEnum::b;
                                           ^
test.cpp:18:25: error: use of undeclared identifier 'test3'; did you mean 'test1'?
    SomeClass::SomeEnum test3 = SomeClass::SomeEnum::c;
                        ^~~~~
                        test1
test.cpp:16:25: note: 'test1' declared here
    SomeClass::SomeEnum test1 = SomeClass::SomeEnum::a;
                        ^
test.cpp:18:24: error: expected ';' after expression
    SomeClass::SomeEnum test3 = SomeClass::SomeEnum::c;
                       ^
                       ;
test.cpp:18:16: error: no member named 'SomeEnum' in 'SomeClass'
    SomeClass::SomeEnum test3 = SomeClass::SomeEnum::c;
    ~~~~~~~~~~~^
test.cpp:18:44: error: 'SomeEnum' is not a class, namespace, or enumeration
    SomeClass::SomeEnum test3 = SomeClass::SomeEnum::c;
                                           ^
1 warning and 12 errors generated.
```

I'm not totally sure what the issue is. Am I not allowed to nest enum classes inside other classes? Why does it compile with no warnings on Linux but completely break in MacOS?

Additionally, what *is* the difference between an enum class? My understanding is that enum classes are generally better practice, but I don't understand when you'd want to use one over the other.

Answer (score 0):

In order to have support for scoped enumerations (`enum class`) you must compile with `-std=c++11` (or higher: `c++14`/`c++17`/`c++20`) since C++11 introduced them. This is what the first warning is telling you. The declaration is ill-formed pre-C++11 which is why you then get the following errors. This is not specific to the `enum class` being nested in another class.

Except for quite old versions, GCC defaults to `-std=c++14` or `-std=c++17`, which is why you don't see an error or warning on Linux. Apple clang (which is what g++ really is a misleading alias for on Mac) defaults to `-std=c++98`, which is why you must manually enable C++11 or later. (Upstream clang also defaults to a more recent standard revision in non-obsolete versions.)

In C++11 or later mode there is nothing wrong with your code.

The reasons to prefer `enum class` over plain `enum` can be found e.g. in the question [Why is enum class preferred over plain enum?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18335861/why-is-enum-class-preferred-over-plain-enum).