# Enum in structure

Tags: c++, qt, struct, enums

My question is not really hard but I can't find a proper answer on the web to my problem.

I define a `.h file` that contains a struct and declare some enum in it. I want to use that struct in another `.cpp file`. But the compilation return me error.

Here's my code `variableStruct.h file` :

```
struct variableSupervision {
    std::string Donnees;

    enum TYPE
    {
      ENUM,
      INT,
      FLOAT,
      BOOL
    };

    enum UNITE
    {
      ETAT,
      A,
      V,
      TBC,
      DEGREEE
    };

    enum IN
    {
      SYSTEMMONITOR,
      MODEMANAGEMENT
    };

    enum OUT
    {
      SLIDECONTROL,
      MODEMANAGEMENT,
      HMICONTROL,
      MOTORCONTROL
    };


    enum GET {X};

    std::string Commentaire ;
};
```

The error is : `redeclaration Of MODEMANAGEMENT`. I don't understand why, because they are in two different enum. Should I create different separate file for each enum ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [namespaces for enum types - best practices](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/482745/namespaces-for-enum-types-best-practices)

Comment: This use C++11 solution, won't work, because i'm not using this type compilator, so there's no duplication.

Comment: Putting the enums in different files won't help... they need to be in different namespaces or classes to avoid the identifier clash.  You can create e.g. `class In { public: enum Enum { X, Y }; In(Enum e) : e_(e) { } operator Enum() const { return e_; } };` etc. then refer unambiguously to `In::X`.  Separately, best to avoid multi-letter all-uppercase identifiers - they're traditionally used only by the preprocessor, and if you have clashes with the preprocessor they can be very confusing and aggravating to debug.

Comment: Thanks, this seem realy complicated just for 1 variable, is there a way to to it in .h file without create a class ?

Comment: How about renaming to `MODEMANAGEMENT_OUT` and `MODEMANAGEMENT_IN`. This way is simple and less error prone.

Comment: You either use the class, or you use `namespace In { enum Enum { X, Y }; }` but then the type name is more verbose: `In::Enum`.

Comment: @40two It is possible, but not really clean :/

Comment: @TonyD didn't work, tells me expected a declaration for the namespace In

Comment: @EvansBelloeil [here's proof it does work on ideone.com](http://ideone.com/54Z7mU) - what did you do?

Comment: @TonyD namespace IN { enum Enum { MODEMANAGEMENT, SYSTEMMONITOR};}

Comment: And?  There's nothing wrong with that.  You haven't still got a conflicting `enum IN` defined earlier?  Just append your current code to the question so I can have a proper look if you can't work it out....

Comment: No conflict with another enum, I don't understand why it doesn't work. But namespace In is underline in red with expected a declaration

Comment: That might mean the line before `namespace` is missing a semicolon, or you're trying to put the namespace inside a function or class?  Again, post your current code if you want further help....

Comment: @TonyD Someone in the answer told me it was impossible to do in a structure.

Comment: @EvansBelloeil: the answer says "they can't be placed at the ***same*** structure" - that's true... you can place each `enum` into a ***separate*** `class`, `struct` or `namespace`.

Comment: @TonyD Yes but I want them place in the same structure

Comment: Then change the names... your pick.

Comment: "Yes but I want them place in the same structure" You already know by now that you can't place enumerators with same name in one structure. The fact that you want it is irrelevant. It can't be done using C-style enums. That's it. End of the ride.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since C++11 you can use `enum class` instead of `enum` to solve this problem.

If you can't use C++11 for some reason you should prefix your values like this:

```
enum IN
{
  IN_SYSTEMMONITOR,
  IN_MODEMANAGEMENT
};

enum OUT
{
  OUT_SLIDECONTROL,
  OUT_MODEMANAGEMENT,
  OUT_HMICONTROL,
  OUT_MOTORCONTROL
};
```

or they can't be placed at the same structure, so you have to move the declarations to different namespaces. (EDIT: or different class / structure as it said below.)

Comment: ... or different class/structure.

Comment: How to use different namespace ?

Comment: If you want to declare them in the same structure, you can't do that.